# I am trying to test by requesting GET in POSTMAN to check whether data is received or not. But showing such errors

Tags: firebase, postman, google-cloud-functions

Postman error.

Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://108.59.80.67/elasticsearch/posts/post/_search?q=*.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General

Firebase error

```
RequestError: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 108.59.80.67:80
    at new RequestError (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:877:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1296:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Javascript code

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');

    const request = require('request-promise')

    exports.indexPostsToElastic = functions.database.ref('/posts/{post_id}')
    .onWrite((change,context) => {
    let postData = change.after.val();
    let post_id = context.params.post_id;

    console.log('Indexing post:', postData);

    let elasticSearchConfig = functions.config().elasticsearch;
    let elasticSearchUrl = elasticSearchConfig.url + 'posts/post/' + 
     post_id;
    let elasticSearchMethod = postData ? 'POST' : 'DELETE';

    let elasticSearchRequest = {
        method: elasticSearchMethod,
        url: elasticSearchUrl,
        auth:{
            username: elasticSearchConfig.username,
            password: elasticSearchConfig.password,
        },
        body: postData,
        json: true
      };

      return request(elasticSearchRequest).then(response => {
         console.log("ElasticSearch response", response);
         return null;
      });
      });
```

Comment: Which payment plan is your Firebase project on?  And please edit your question to show all relevant code.

Comment: Blaze. Pay as you go

Comment: And edit your question to show the code?

Comment: done. one more thing my payment issue is on hold

Comment: What do you mean "my payment issue is on hold"?

Comment: it's showing me payment invalid. Is it because of that?

Comment: Possibly.  You should contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/